# How to make PHP class, extending an abstract class, require a more specific type

Tags: php, zend-framework, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I am using the Table-Data-Gateway pattern.  All of my models which aren't Mappers or DB_Table classes extend Model_Base.  All of my mappers extend `Model_MapperBase`.  All of my DB_Table classes extend `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`.

In all of my mapper classes, I want to enforce that there is a function `map`, which takes a `DB_Row` Object, and the Model class that is maps to.  Ideally, what I would like to be able to do, is in my `Model_MapperBase`, I would have:

```
abstract public function map(Model_Base $model, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row);
```

And then when I implement it, I would do:

```
public function map(Model_User $user, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row) {
    $user->setId($row->id)
         ->setName($row->name);
    return $user;
}
```

But obviously, that doesn't work, as the abstract function says it should take ANY class that extends Model_Base.  But I would like to ensure that, yes, it MUST be one the extends Model_Base, but then I would like to have the implementations be **more specific**.

The only thing I can think of is something like:

```
public function map(Model_Base $user, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row) {
  if (get_class($user) != 'Model_User') { 
      throw new Exception('Invalid Class');
  } else {
      $user->setId($row->id)
           ->setName($row->name);
      return $user;
  }
}
```

But that just seems, wrong on a certain level.  Is there a better way to do this?

Edit:  So, not being satisfied with the below, I have resorted to this:

```
final public function map(Model_Base $model, 
                          Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row)
{
    if (get_class($this) != get_class($model).'Mapper') {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Class: Expected " . substr(get_class($this), 0, strlen($this)-6) . '. Received ' .
            get_class($model) . '.');
    }
    return $this->mapImplementation($model, $row);
}

abstract protected function mapImplementation(Model_Base $model, 
                                              Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row);
```

And then have my Mapper Classes implement the mapImplementation method, but always call the map method.  This accomplishes what I would like, effectively, but seems a little contrived, and only happens to work because, as of right now, all my Mapper Classes have a class with the same name sans 'mapper'.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do, which would not depend on a naming scheme or throwing an exception in each class?

EDIT:  I am not looking for "use instanceOf instead of get_class" - that is essentially the same thing for my purposes, and if I plan on extending my non-base mapper classes, I will make that change.  I am looking for a way to enforce the correct class type, without manually throwing an exception.

Comment: What is wrong in `public function map(Model_User $user, ...`? Is there a STRICT error?

Comment: It spits out `Fatal error: Declaration of Model_UserMapper::map() must be compatible with Model_MapperBase::map(Model_Base $model, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row) in /application/models/UserMapper.php `

Comment: So I think your solution is applicable, however I'd rather use `if($user instanceof Model_User) throw ...` because this will work too if you extend `Model_User` class. Why do you write "it seems to be wrong on a certain level"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much this gains but one approach would be to create your map method on the abstract class like this

```
final public function map(Model_Base $user, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row) {
    return $this->_map($user, $row);
}
```

then for your User Mapper

```
public function _map(Model_User $user, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row) {
    $user->setId($row->id)
         ->setName($row->name);
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Wow.  At first I saw this and was like "that is exactly what my last update had."  Then I realized this is actually doing exactly what I want, I did not realize my abstract method could call a function it did not yet "know" existed.  Very nice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As this is not possible to change method's header while extending the abstract class, I think your solution is good.

But in my opinion modifying the code to

```
public function map(Model_Base $user, Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract $row) {
if (!$user instanceof Model_User)
  throw new Exception('Invalid Class');
```

would be better, because it is more flexible if you'd wish to override this method in descendant classes while using something like `parent::map(...)`.

If `classA` extends `classB`, and `$objectA` and `$objectB` are instances of the classes, respectively, `$objectA instanceof classB` is `true` but `get_class($objectA) === 'classA'`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP requires that the method signatures must be the same.

> the signatures of the methods must match, i.e. the type hints and the number of required arguments must be the same.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

This makes sense because your abstract class is defining a contract for classes that use it and you are trying to change that contract in your implementation.  Naively, I should expect to be able to pass a `Model_Base` to this function anywhere and it should be able to work.

So in order to enforce a stricter type in derived classes you will need to some sort of type checking.   I prefer the same method as in the other answer using `instanceof`.  This allows for extensions of that class to be used without having to modify the code.